# javascript redirect not triggered when user goes on scrollbar

Tags: javascript, redirect

So i have a simple javascript code which redirects a visitor when he leaves the active window. The problem is that when a user is going to the scroll bar on the right, it also redirects...

How can I get it so it doesn't redirect when a user leaves the page to hit to the scrollbar but it does when the user leaves to the addressbar?

What is the best solution?

Here's the code i have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
    }
    else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
    }
}
addEvent(window,"load",function(e) {
    addEvent(document, "mouseout", function(e) {
        e = e ? e : window.event;
        var from = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;
        if (!from || from.nodeName == "HTML") {
            // stop your drag event here
            // for now we can just use an alert
            //alert("left window");
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
        }
    });
});
</script>
Goodbye - just mouseout the window...
```

You can view an example on http://www.marketingillusionist.com/test.html

Comment: _“which redirects a visitor when he leaves the active window”_ – sounds like terrible UX …

Answer (score 0):

Its not the scrollbar causing the issue. Its the margin on 'body'. There is default margin in browsers for 'body'. Try setting css like this and see if it works:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body
    {
    margin:0;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: That didn't work. I tried adding the code and viewing the page in both FF and Chrome